# Puppet agent in Red hat and SUSE

Tags: redhat, puppet, suse

I have a problem in running puppet agent in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.4 and SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11. In both cases, when I ran "puppet agent --test --verbose", I could see no error and the configuration was applied. However, when I ran "service puppet restart", while the result said that the service was stopped and started okay, the configuration was not applied. That is the problem.

For Red Hat, I could not be able to find the log file at "/var/log/puppet" (the directory was empty). However, for SUSE, I found the log file at "/var/log/puppet/puppet.log" and it recorded a couple of errors: "Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run. Could not send report: getaddrinfo: Name or service not know". It is weird because once the "puppet agent --test" could be executed successfully, it implied that the server's address could be resolved !!!

Do you have any idea of how this problem happened and how to fix it.

Thanks,
Henry

P/S: below is the content of puppet.conf and site.pp at the server and puppet.conf at the client

```
#puppet.conf at the server
[main]
logdir=/var/log/puppet
vardir=/var/lib/puppet
ssldir=/var/lib/puppet/ssl
rundir=/var/run/puppet
factpath=$vardir/lib/facter
templatedir=$confdir/templates
prerun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-pre
postrun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-post
[master]
ssl_client_header = SSL_CLIENT_S_DN
ssl_client_verify_header = SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY
dns_alt_names = puppet, server_name

#site.pp at the server    
node default{
}
node 'client_name' {
   include 'client_config'
}

#puppet.conf at the client
[main]
logdir = /var/log/puppet
rundir = /var/run/puppet
ssldir = $vardir/ssl
server = server_name
certname = client_name
report = true
pluginsync = true
[agent]
classfile = $vardir/classes.txt
localconfig = $vardir/localconfig
```

Comment: Could you share your puppet.conf and site.pp? (remove sensitive data)

It looks like your agent cannot resolve the Puppet master's address.

Comment: Note that the same configuration works for ubuntu. The problem only happens in SUSE and Red Hat. It is true that the error message implies the Puppet master's address cannot be resolved. However, if this is the case, how could the execution of "puppet agent --test" work?

Comment: Perhaps the 'search' option from resolv.conf doesn't work when it's running as a daemon, could you add '[ip] puppet' to your hosts file?

Comment: I added the mapping "server_ip server_name" to /etc/hosts and tried to execute "service puppet restart" again. But it still did not work and returned the same error (in SUSE). BTW: for Red hat, where is the log file of puppet? I tried to search all place but could not find it.

Comment: It seems that someone also has the similar issue https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/puppet-users/cBABZgHgsE4 The puppet version installed in my SLES is 2.6.18, which is the latest one in the repository. What should I do?